# where to use getInitialProps when auto-direct from one page to another

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

In my application I am auto-directing from '/' to '/PageOne' like this:

```
const Home = () => {
  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    router.push('/pageone', undefined, { shallow: true });
  }, []);

  return <PageOne />;
};
```

and in my PageOne, I want to use getInitialProps like:

```
const pageOne = (data) => {

  return (
    <Layout>
      ...
    </Layout>
  );
};

pageOne.getInitialProps = async (
  ctx: NextPageContext
): Promise<{ data }> => {
  const response = await someAPICall()
  return {
    data: response.data
  };
};

export default pageOne;
```

This will cause an error in my Home page because I referenced to PageOne using  and it is missing the param "data", but I'm not able to pass the data to  because the data are not there when rendering Home page.

Shall I call the API to get data in Home page instead of PageOne? If I do so, will refreshing PageOne leads to another API call to get most recent data or the API will be called only when refreshing Home page?

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `shallow` routing because that is meant to just change the url - a good use case is adding a query string or indicating to the application that something has changed when its bookmarked, e.g: `?chat=true` (*not your usecase*)

> Shallow routing allows you to change the URL without running data fetching methods again, that includes getServerSideProps, getStaticProps, and getInitialProps.

It's one of the caveats called out in this page => https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/shallow-routing#caveats

If not already, you would benefit from starting to use global state in your application

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-redux

or you can use in-built features:
https://www.basefactor.com/global-state-with-react